# Google Prettify Line numbers and Font

Tags: css, prettify

I have been playing with Prettify and I got it working quickly. However when I tried to change the font in the css file i can't seem to see any change in the browser. I am using Silver Stripe as a CMS. In the CSS file from the website I have:

```
.typography * {
    font-family: Ariel, sans-serif;
}
```

I have a separate CSS for prettify (and I know it works because the bg color changes, etc. only the font-family and font-size doesn't. Strangely font-weight does work).

```
pre.prettyprint, code.prettyprint {
    font-family:monospace; /* doesn't work why? */
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 8pt; /* doesn't work */
    background-color: #333; /* this works */
}
```

I am using Safari. I don't understand what I am doing wrong? I only seem to get an Arial font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Safari doesn't support the monospace correctly. See more about it:
http://www.markwyner.com/post/16123207332/safari-vs-monospace-fonts 
Here you can find the appropriate font for Safari to support: 
http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html
For the not working measurement unit - `pt` try using another unit to see if it gives you any result. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks that's a start and might help. I think the CSS from the CMS and the CSS used to control Prettify's style are conflicting but I will write an update when I find out. Thx for your answer.

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied with the answer, you should accept it, that's how it works. Good luck!

Comment: Well lets say it's probably now what caused the problem. It's probably more a conflict with the CMS but I will accept it for now and will update the question later, if/when I find more. Thank you-